# How can I change weapon upgrades?

Tags: doom-2016

I don't understand weapon modifications mechanics.

I've found weapon upgrade drone or something like this in first level and upgraded my shotgun to have explosive rounds as secondary attack.

Now I want to try another upgrade - how can I switch between them? Do I need to find another upgrade drone? Can I run first mission again to get that drone one more time and than continue my campaign?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade Drones can only be used once per playthrough, and replaying a level won't allow you to reuse a drone. There's a few in every level, though, so you won't need to wait long to get another upgrade. Once you've unlocked both upgrades on a weapon you can swap between them at anytime, even in combat, you just need to press the upgrade swap button. It takes a few seconds for the swap to occur, though.

Comment: How many this drones are in game? Should I choose upgrades wisely or eventually I'll get all of them?

Comment: @arghtype I'm not sure how many there are, but I'm pretty sure there's enough to ulock every weapon, along with a few extra, so I wouldn't worry about saving them.  In fact near the end of the game I didn't even bother trying to find them anymore, since I didn't even need them.

Answer (score 4):

On PC, press <kbd>R</kbd> to swap between upgrades